# Missing widgets bar/docker

Tags: app-widgets

It seems I have missed the option for adding widgets on Android 5.1 (this is on a chinese branded phone), maybe I touched on the wrong place. Now, when I long tap over home screen I get nothing but a white rectangle that allows me to move the clock and the bottom icons but nothing about adding widgets. I remember I had the widgets option but I somehow missed it. Device has installed a few apps (firefox and rss reader) and uses the stock launcher3 (I already tried to clear data and cache with not avail). Thanks for any hint you can give me!

Comment: No solution but a workaround: Use Nova Launcher or Apex Launcher - lightweight, customizable and easy to set up :)

Comment: OP here :-)Yeah, thanks. I already did that (well, not Nova but Catapult instead) and worked fine -widgets can be accessed from here- so something went really bad with the stock launcher. In the meantime I'm going to find a better launcher but is there any way to reinstall a stock app without resetting the full phone? Thanks!

Comment: You could try to reset the app settings - yes. Normally you'd have to go into Settings -> Apps -> Launcher3 (make sure that you can see all apps - you might have to swipe from right to left to change which apps are shown) -> Delete  Data and cache. Then you could try it again. Best case: it works - worst case your homescreen layout was deleted and you have to do it again and you still can't add widgets :P

Comment: Tested that way.. many times. But seems to be of no effect. I mean, clearing cache, clearing data, stopping the service... and all I get is the "welcome" message again, restored icons but same effect when long-tap on homescreen. It's a really weird behaviour.